# GMB API upload image returns 'Fetching image failed.'

Tags: python, django, google-my-business-api

I have an issue when using the GMB API for uploading media items.

In my code, I am able to successfully request and obtain the resourceName as explained in the API docs. I then use the resourceName to upload an image as bytes. This also works very well and I get a 200 response.

After this, I then begin the media upload using the steps documented in the API, however this time is fails and returns

> {'error': {'code': 400, 'message': 'Request contains an invalid argument.', 'status': 'INVALID_ARGUMENT', 'details': [{'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.mybusiness.v4.ValidationError', 'errorDetails': [{'code': 1000, 'message': 'Fetching image failed.'}]}]}}

I have tried the same steps using the Oauth Playground and sending a curl request as well but it always fails in the last step yielding the same error.

My code written in Python using the Django web framework:

```
    response = requests.post(f'https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/{accountId}/locations/{locationId}/media:startUpload', headers=HEADERS)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        resource_name = response.json()['resourceName']
        with open('C:/Users/nevog/Desktop/testimonial-2.jpg', 'rb') as f:
            data = f.read()
        params = {
            'upload_type': 'media',
        }
        response = requests.post(f'https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/upload/v1/media/{resource_name}', data=data, params=params, headers=HEADERS)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            print("upload successful")
            request_body =   {
                    "mediaFormat": "PHOTO",
                    "locationAssociation": {
                        "category": "ADDITIONAL"
                        },
                    "dataRef": {
                        "resourceName": resource_name
                        },
            }
            response = requests.post(f'https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/{accountId}/locations/{locationId}/media', json=request_body, headers=HEADERS)
            if response.status_code == 200:
                print("successful")
            else:
                print(response.json())
        else:
            print("Error uploading media")
    else:
        print("Error in fetching resource name", response.json())
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and found this topic first. I looked further and it seems to be an ongoing unresolved issue. The report of the unresolved error can be found here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/293595949

If, like me, you need to add a photo to LocalPost, it currently seems that the only solution is to temporarily upload the file to your own server and pass it to Google via a public http address.

```
local_post["media"] = [{
            "sourceUrl": post_media_url,
            "media_format": "PHOTO"
}]
```